# On days when Kohanim Duchan, why do the Kohanim only do it once and not in each Shemoneh Esrei?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, birchas-kohanim

On days when the Kohanim [Duchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing#Procedure), why do the Kohanim only do it once (during Mussaf) and not in each [Shemoneh Esrei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah)?

[revised question]

Comment: Can you explain your question, please? To me, "Duchan" and "Birkat Kohanim" seem to be synonyms: they refer to the same thing, and that thing is of necessity in _sh'mone esre_.

Comment: nevermind, that answers my question. I was confused why we do the chazan/kein yehi ratzon version in shacharit when we actually duchan with kohanim in mussaf. it's because its required for each shmone esrei, I thought it was just once a day. but that does raise another question I'll have to ask; on days when the Kohanim Duchan, why do the Kohanim only do it once and not in each Shomneh Esrei?

Comment: @zaq that's a very good question. Can you edit this question into that other question? Or just give me the go-ahead...

Comment: I'm confused... Why do you think they don't do birkat kohanim in Shacharit? Perhaps the kohen simply arrived too late (that has happened by us in the past :) )?

Comment: @AviD, In the Machzor, Shacharit just has the chazan/kein yehi ratzon version for when the Kohanim don't Duchan, and only Mussaf has the Kohen version. From experience, I've only seen the Kohanim Duchan only once a day, even when there is a Kohen there. (That originally lead me to think the requirement was to do birkat kohanim only once a day, msh210 clarified that for me.)

Comment: Which Machzor? For which Chag? At least for 3 R'galim, my Rinat Yisrael has the Kohen version in Shacharit too. RH too.

Comment: Something just occurred to me, this is probably a *Eretz Yisrael* / *Galut* type of thing, isn't it? I keep forgetting that Birkat Kohanim is not done all the time outside of Israel :)

Comment: Yep, that's definitely what is leading to the confusion. I should specify. Out-side Israel, The Kohanim only Duchan on Rosh Hashana, Yom Kippur, Sukkot, Pesach, Shavuot and Shemini Atzeret. Except for Neilah on Yom Kippur, it's done only once a day, during mussaf.

Comment: And that's for _Ashk'nazim_ in _chutz laaretz_. Many _S'faradim_ there do _birkas kohanim_ at every _shacharis_ and _musaf_ (and at _mincha_ (and I suppose _n'ila_) on a fast day).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rema (Orach Chaim 128:44) [says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&pgnum=170) that since the point of the Ashkenazic custom to limit Birkas Kohanim to Yom Tov is so that the blessing should be given in a joyous frame of mind, then it is done only at Musaf, since then people are especially happy at the impending prospect of the Yom Tov meal.

(Yom Kippur, of course, is the exception. I believe there are indeed Ashkenazic congregations that have Birkas Kohanim at Ne'ilah as well, provided of course that it's not too late in the day. Not sure about Minchah.)

Comment: It would be forbidden at Mincha! Perhaps you are referring to Yom Kippur Shacharit?

Comment: @DoubleAA: why would it be forbidden at Minchah? The kohanim won't have drunk before it (unlike a regular Yom Tov).

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch makes an explicit lo plug in 129:1 and IIRC he's quoting straight from the gemara in Taanit. However, since as you say there is no real chashash, were a kohen to go up anyway, we don't remove him (129:2); but he shouldn't go up lechatchila.

Comment: The rama in the seif you quote explicitly discusses different minhagim about shacharit even in chu"l.